# Data loss issue while converting the string from std::string to const char *

Tags: c++, string, yaml-cpp, cppcheck

In this function, passing `string` as an argument (which is having the huge amount of data as a string)...

SendBytes method is defined like this

```
bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendBytes ( const void * pBuf, int iLen )
{
        BYTE * pMy = (BYTE*)pBuf;

        while ( iLen>0 && !m_bError )
        {
                int iLeft = m_iBufferSize - ( m_pBufferPtr-m_pBuffer );
                if ( iLen<=iLeft )
                {
                        printf("iLen is %d\n",iLen);
                        memcpy ( m_pBufferPtr, pMy, iLen );
                        m_pBufferPtr += iLen;
                        break;
                }

                ResizeIf ( iLen );
        }
        return !m_bError;
}

bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendCompressedString ( std::string sStr )
{
    std::cout << sStr << endl;
    const char *cStr = sStr.c_str();
    std::cout << cStr <<endl;

    int iLen = cStr ? strlen(cStr) : 0;
    SendInt ( iLen );
    return SendBytes ( cStr, iLen );
}
```

Tried printing the value of sStr to check whether it has proper data or not.

Then converting the `std::string` to `const char *`

After converting it,tried printing the value of cStr. But it(cStr) actually contains 5% of the actual data(sStr)...

what shall I need to do in order to get the whole data?

Can someone guide me in this regard?

Comment: Does your string have embedded null (`'\0'`) characters?

Comment: The string has the compressed data like this                      xÚì½ëRãÈ¶.ú¿"ö;(Ö<8f>¹ºã0½ò®Ì½^?^Y0à^B^[^ZCÝNìP^H[`<81>mQ¾@¹Vì<88>ó^ZçõÎ<93><9c><91>)ù<86>.¶<85>^L6Ý½ÖìÆ^^<99><92>,¥ò^[×o|úïÿ¸õ½Nkð^_ÿóÿþ<8f>®;ìû~ë?öþc0ºiº<83>¡^G^?Þ^EÃvß<85>?^^ûÁ­ßñZÞ Ù÷^_<87>~Ð<9b>^[è<98>iáXý÷ÿÞû^Ow8ì<9b>ÃF^Sý^Ëû^E<83>:nïnäÞéc^O<86>îp4<80>?<9e>Ü<8e>ßr<87><9e>><88>;^Z¶<83>¾ÿÛ|ðzÃþx8~4£^_½¦ïv^^ûþÓìrÚþ]»^Cÿ^[N<8f>õ^X<{ýG·ù0ý¦çvÍ/ñà
úú^LæämOO<83>?ü^³«<87>uáê½þ0<80>Ë<9b>;^]ü<ý©ïÁYÂß<¹3±

Comment: Compressed data is binary format and you probably should use std::cout.write() rather than formatted << output. @Benjamin is right you probably have null characters that indicate the end of a c-string.
PS. you can't see null characters from a printout or in an editor.

Comment: Are you sure? What do you get if you do this? `int x = std::find(sStr.begin(), sStr.end(), '\0') - sStr.begin(); std::cout << x;`

Comment: @Galik:can u please edit that code and tell me how to get the whole data.?

Comment: Try this:
bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendCompressedString ( std::string sStr )
{
        SendInt ( sStr.size() );
        return SendBytes ( sStr.c_str(), sStr.size() );
} **[see Benjamin's answer]**

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:yes it contain null values in between

Comment: Your problem is that you use a string for storing something else than a string. For arbitrary data, use `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` works for c-strings. That is, null terminated strings. It searches for a `'\0'` character, and returns that character's position as the length of the string. You have compressed binary data, not a c-string. It almost certainly contains a 0 before the end of the string. Use `sStr.size()` instead.

```
SendInt ( sStr.size() );
return SendBytes ( sStr.c_str(), sStr.size() );
```

Comment: Benjamin Lindley:ok.Still I'm getting the same issue...can u please check and tell me whether i've implemented the  correct code which u said.

bool NetOutputBuffer_c::SendCompressedString ( std::string sStr )
{

        std::cout << sStr << endl;

      //  const char *cStr = sStr.c_str();
      //  std::cout << cStr <<endl;
     //   int iLen = cStr ? strlen(cStr) : 0;
        std::cout << sStr.size() << endl;
        std::cout << sStr.c_str() << endl;

        SendInt ( sStr.size() );
        return SendBytes ( sStr.c_str(), sStr.size() );
}

Comment: @user3532122: Is the call to `SendBytes` working? Printing out the c-string still won't work for the same reason that strlen doesn't work. Do you really need that? I assumed it was just your attempt at debugging the failed call to `SendBytes`.

Comment: But if you need it to print the whole string from the c-string (I can't imagine why), then use `std::cout.write(sStr.c_str(), sStr.size());`

Comment: i can able to print the data by following the method what u said....But Now i need to send the whole data which is available in write(sStr.c_str(),sStr.size()) as Byte *  .What shall i need to do inorder to  make it working?